# How I can parse json with arrays by custom order?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, sorting

I am completely newbie in JavaScripts and sorry for my english if it so bad. I have json file looking like that:

```
{
   "posts":[
      {
         "id":2236659,
         "updated_at":"2020-05-02T19:58:43.763-04:00",
         "file":{
            "width":933,
            "height":1200,
            "ext":"png",
            "size":1325351,
            "md5":"d1f501df73f7d1daec07a86657baae01"
         }
      },
      {
         "id":2227726,
         "created_at":"2020-04-23T08:06:37.907-04:00",
         "file":{
            "width":933,
            "height":1200,
            "ext":"png",
            "size":1182791,
            "md5":"112cadaaaa89841e8bb7633ba272a409"
         }
      },
      {
         "id":2218681,
         "created_at":"2020-04-16T07:56:56.849-04:00",
         "file":{
            "width":933,
            "height":1200,
            "ext":"png",
            "size":1241188,
            "md5":"c3c13b8e5c72913fa7db03ffc8b6f3c4"
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

The problem that the order of posts is incorrect. It sorted by ascending of id. Real json file contain more than 3 post. I have order list. How I can sort it with custom order that I typed.
For example: I want get md5 with this order: 2227726,2218681,2236659

Comment: so you need them to be ordered according to MD5 and not the id?

Comment: No by id via id order list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope now I got it right :)

```
const md5s = listOfIds.map(id => data.posts.find(post => post.id === id))
```

where listOfIds is the list of ids like [2149825,2149832,2149838...]

The result is array of md5's in the order specified in listOfIds array

Comment: In my answer the posts array sorted the way the ids of posts are 2227726,2218681,2236659 as you suggested. If you want to sort the array by ids in an ascending order, just use data.posts.sort((a,b) => a.id - b.id)

Comment: I need to understand what do you need exactly. Do you want to sort the posts by their id or md5? And in which order, asc or desc?

Comment: What is your runtime environment? Is it browser or Node.js? Maybe you should try console.log(yourObjectName)? It seems like you're trying to use 'alert' function that represents objects as string.

Comment: I can post a full script if you specify what order you exactly need, on which parameter of your Post object the sorting needs to be applied and in which order, asc or desc :)

Comment: @Tofi You need just a list of md5's in that order, right? I'll update the answer

Comment: Okay, you mean you need the md5's list in the same order as the original posts list from the json file?

Comment: I can't understand where this 2227726,2218681,2236659 order comes from. If I could, there would be no problem helping you with a solution.

Comment: I have list like this [2149825,2149832,2149838,2149843,2149850,2149856,2149862,2149873,2149896,2149905,2149915,2149930,2149452,2157382,2164352,2171550,2178125,2185897,2192911,2201779,2209896,2218681,2227726,2236659] this list show order of posts that must be. The json file just contain information. Some time there not any order. I need sort md5 with correct order via this list. By json first come  2149452 because it's smallest value. But in list first come 2149825. List contain correct order

Comment: If the list id order array format is correct (looks like [2149825,2149832,2149838...]) it will work 100%. Alert won't log the contents of an array to you. You may try alert(JSON.stringify(result)).

Comment: Yes. It work. I use `for ( x=0 ; x< posts.length;x++) { document.write(md5[x].file.md5) `. I accidentally deleted x why it not wanted find md5. sorry for taked to much time all work nice now. Google translate don't translate correct from my language.

Comment: @Tofi glad that we finally found a solution, good luck buddy!

Answer (score 1):

basically you can use the [sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) function, it would like something like this:

```js
// expected result 2227726,2218681,2236659
const data = {
  "posts": [{
      "id": 2236659,
      "updated_at": "2020-05-02T19:58:43.763-04:00",
      "file": {
        "width": 933,
        "height": 1200,
        "ext": "png",
        "size": 1325351,
        "md5": "d1f501df73f7d1daec07a86657baae01"
      }
    },
    {
      "id": 2227726,
      "created_at": "2020-04-23T08:06:37.907-04:00",
      "file": {
        "width": 933,
        "height": 1200,
        "ext": "png",
        "size": 1182791,
        "md5": "112cadaaaa89841e8bb7633ba272a409"
      }
    },
    {
      "id": 2218681,
      "created_at": "2020-04-16T07:56:56.849-04:00",
      "file": {
        "width": 933,
        "height": 1200,
        "ext": "png",
        "size": 1241188,
        "md5": "c3c13b8e5c72913fa7db03ffc8b6f3c4"
      }
    }
  ]
}

const customComparer = {
  2227726: 1,
  2218681: 2,
  2236659: 3
}

const sortFn = (a, b) => {
  return customComparer[a.id] - customComparer[b.id]
}
const result = data.posts.sort(sortFn)

console.log(result)
```

notice that if you want this to be scalable, this is not the right way to sort an array, you are trying to sort it in a not a regular way.